# SQlite update adding some

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to add some float values to the table. 
using Sqlite update command

```
   float Cu= row.Cells["Cu"].Value != null && float.TryParse(row.Cells["Cu"].Value.ToString(), out Cu) ? Cu: 0;
```

So here I am making sure the value in the row is not null and also float. 
If true, then insert the value, else insert 0.

```
    Sqlite Update command
     insCmdVesselData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Copper",Cu);
  public string SQL_updateVesselData = @"UPDATE
             [VesselData]
            SET


    [Copper]=@Copper,
    [Nickel]=@Nickel,
    [Phosphorous]=@Phosphorous,
    [Silicon]=@Silicon,
[Manganese]=@Manganese,

where

         [PlantId] = @PlantId and FileId= @FileId

Here Copper,Nickel is a Numeric in the Database. 
Suppose my value of Cu=0.07, during this update, it is adding a number 0.0700000002980232. it the value is 0.5, it updates with 0.529999971389771. Not sure y its adding all these garbage at the end
```

Thank u
Sun

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a float, I used Decimal and it solved the problem